# C++ Code Naming Style Converter, Formatter or Beautifier

Tags: c++, coding-style, naming

I am looking for a good tool that can automatically convert c++ naming styles, such as change method name from "SetPosition()" to "setPosition()", and class name "CPoint" to "Point". Seems most of formatters have no such feature. Thanks.

Comment: Seems to me that both of those could be done by search & replace.  Do you have something more complicated in mind?

Comment: There are too many methods and classes. It is time-consuming and easy to make a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code formatters don't do renaming of functions. What you need is a refactoring tool that can perform rename. If your project isn't very big then Devexpress Refactor! for C++ (free) might be of help. It will involve some manual work, but it'll be safer than search and replace. Qt Creator has a rename reporting built in an I have found it to be quite reliable (hasn't messed up so far unlike some dedicated refactoring tools).

If manual work using refactoring tools is too much then you can use clangs pieces to build a tool that performs the refactorings automatically, but this is probably more work than the semi-manual process with refactoring tools.

Answer (score 3):

[You can manipulate C++ source using Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Tooling.html), although you might have to [write a bit of code](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/06/08/basic-source-to-source-transformation-with-clang/) to do the conversion that you have in mind.

For example, the Clang infrastructure would allow you to write a program that iterates over all class method names in a given source file.  You could then programatically convert any pascal-case method names that you encounter into camel-case names.